# Automatically disable the "Manage Your Server" screen on Windows 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, login, group-policy

Is there a line I can add to my login scripts or something with GPO to prevent the "Manage Your Server" screen from showing up when I log in to a Windows 2003 Server?

[image: manage your server screen]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this via a GPO

http://www.techcow.com/tech-tips/windows-2003/how_to_disable_manage_your_server_wizard_in_windows_2003.html

Comment: I like that the link includes the 20+ admin users that will also see the screen.  It's not just about number of servers but number of admin users as well.

Comment: Because links are ephemeral... Start>Run: type in gpedit.msc   (that will launch a Group Policy Object Editor console).  
Then go to:Computer configuration - Administrative templates - System - Do not display Manage Your Server page at logon

Answer (score 3):

Why not click the little check box that reads

```
Don't display this page at logon
```

Or do you just have so many servers to do that to it's beyond reasonable.

Comment: +1 we usually do this to all servers. Maybe the little checkbox isnt as obvious as it should be.  I am sure its probably as simple as changing a 1 to a 0 in the registry somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late but might be handy so check here :

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Setup\Welcome
```